# Tenda F303 not working after firmware upgrade

Tags: networking, router, updates, firmware

I have a tenda F303 and I needed to port forward a game but on the internet I seen that I need to upgrade the firmware to port forward and some more things.I opened www.tendacn.com and I searched my router model and I pressed the download button and selected the upgrade.I opened my router settings tab and I pressed to upgrade I selected the corect file and I started the process.The router rebooted in the login screen (192.168.0.1/login.asp) but the page was blank.I tryed to reset the router from the reset button from the back of the case but didn't work.I need help as quick as you can!Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you followed the reset procedure correctly? http://www.microcenter.com/tech_center/article/7995/How_to_reset_the_Tenda_F303_Wireless_Router_to_Default_Settings

Comment: Yes I did that.

Comment: But didn't work

Comment: I can suggest (1) leaving it unpowered for a whole minute, (2) using an Ethernet cable to connect to it, and (3) using 192.168.0.1 *without* the "login.asp" - they might have changed the name of the page.

Comment: when I type 192.168.0.1 and press ENTER it automaticaly add /login.asp to the adress.And I use ethernet cable for the wan and my computer is connected with cable but I also I tryed wireless connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to V11.13.01.23_EN from V11.13.01.06_EN and had the same issue.
 The web page of the router wouldn't open.
I disconnected the power and all the data (ethernet) cables. Connected the power cable and hold the WPS/Reset button for good two minutes.
Router restart couple times, then I connected my laptop with the patch cord. This helped, I can login into the router again.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Followed the process exactly and it worked like a charm.

Comment: How you connect with the patch cord?

Answer (score 0):

If you have cleared your browser cache and does a `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew` and not getting an IP address, the router is likely bricked. If you are getting an IP address, then attempt to access the  router at http://192.168.0.1. If the web page does not open or you are not getting an IP address, then attempt a reset using the instructions from [Microcenter's tech support site](http://www.microcenter.com/tech_center/article/7995/How_to_reset_the_Tenda_F303_Wireless_Router_to_Default_Settings).

If a factory default does not work and return functionality to the unit, then the flash is corrupted and the device is likely "bricked", and as far as I can find the F303 does not have an emergency recovery mode to FTP/TFTP the firmware for disaster recovery.

There is some mention in the F311 being recoverable after soldering in a USB Serial uart for communications to the unit as described [here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=64016), so I would image an even lower end router would be similar, if it is possible at all.

This is a sub-$20 router from multiple vendors ([here](http://www.walmart.com/ip/48757008?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=51&adid=22222222227036320428&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=57512637818&wl4=&wl5=pla&wl6=89879501618&veh=sem) and [here](http://www.neobits.com/tenda_technology_f303_tenda_network_f303_wireless_p8596143.html?atc=gbp&gclid=Cj0KEQjwvZq6BRC9kfq2zKfQ_94BEiQAOeUVC3g5FHOzYKRqMxkXr6s7ItNoKn-NSgDBvFTazkx0TJ0aAie68P8HAQ) are examples, NOT shopping recommendations), unless you have the equipment and expertise handy I would suggest replacing the unit.